# How long should I wait for an answer on here?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

How long should I wait for an answer to my question [18.04.2 authentication error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131817/18-04-2-authentication-error)
on here, and in the meantime is there anything I can do to make it more answerable?

I've already included a fair bit of detail so afraid adding more might overwhelm potential responders and discourage them,  but would very much welcome dialogue about editing my question if that might help.

Answer (score 14):

Questions at *askubuntu* are answered from a voluntary community, so there is no ticket system that reminds people to answer questions.
It happens that questions are replaced by newer ones and people will miss them even if they are good, because most wont scroll down a lot or even visit the next page(s).

That happens e.g. if they are posted on Sunday morning 8am CEST like yours, when lots of people will still be in bed. This, plus it seems a very specific issue that not many people or maybe even no one had themselves, so there are not many people that are able to help.

There is a pending edit on your question, and once that edit is approved, it will be on the front page again.

Comment: while I was writing this, someone already answered your question =)

Comment: There's also a good case for tagging questions well. For instance, a lot of people watch for [command-line] tag. Specialized topics such as particular hardware are watched by far fewer people. So if one wants to have more eyeballs on a question, the more relevant tags you have ( with emphasis on relevant) the more people you can reach

Answer (score 7):

We get *a lot* of questions on Askubuntu, so aside from giving as much information as you can which is nicely covered by the help page

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

it’s also very important to present your question in the right way – through proper formatting:

- [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)
- [Markdown help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

These help pages shows how you can format text as code, create lists, link other webpages, apply syntax highlighting and much more – things that help possible answerers read and understand your question better.